# Not granted any authorities

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm my Hybris 6 app I'm receiving the B2BCustomers from an external web-service. Then, I validate them and proceed to create them in the database throught the B2BCustomerModel and the modelService.

However, I always get an exception saying "Not granted any authorities" from spring. The customer has valid groups, a default b2bunit and so.

I don't understand why do I get this message.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Cris.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that the specific user is not assigned any privileges and/or roles. Only confirming proper groups is not enough. This error is usually thrown by spring authentication framework when a user is not assigned any privileges then it gives such an error.